# How to determine if a script is started by cron?

Tags: 7, cron

I have a script that run in some cases when some event occur. It also run when cron run (cron.php) or the "Run cron button" from admin panel is clicked.

How can I determine that from script that is started by drupal cron.php?

Comment: Inspect `debug_backtrace()`, the first entry will have the name of the originating file in it (index.php or cron.php)

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dup if someone wants to dig.

Answer (score 1):

You may check your $_SERVER globals in the script.

A better way, I think, would be to pass a parameter with your call to the script that separates the caller (I.e when you call it from the HOOK_cron(), add a myFunc(..., $caller="cron") to your call. And declare myFunc(..., $caller=null) as default parameter.

If this is not possible, you may set a session variable in HOOK_cron and check that in your script.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a script during cron, you should do so by invoking `hook_cron` in a module like this:

```
function my_module_cron() {
  invoke_custom_script();
}
```

When you do this, you could tell the script, that it is being called from cron by adding a parameter etc. This could be done like this.

```
function my_module_cron() {
  invoke_custom_script(array('context' => 'cron'));
}
```